I swap from SOL to Base ETH, but do not receive Base ETH
I swapped 38 SOL to Base ETH on Phantom, but I do not receive Base ETH in my wallet.
My tx is: 3fz4SeNa2pieFw3zR6eY17y1Cw4JUoXWvfNAUX2Cx4Z2tKJazfrwUZpgidXG83ZQ5z4KqvYuXo8RVGdrFNGc9oxA
My Solana wallet is: FBx2gRC4WRnuygT5cLgEvjATWZ7dkdUFnoDhk15RsT3w
Is there anything I can do?
